# How could i prevent to be stucked after execute channel.send if the channel has slowmode/cooldown on it? Discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have an issue with sending messages to a discord channel.

If the channel is in timeout due to discord channel cooldown, then the channel.send(msg) function will block.

```
        if channel.id in channelID:
                await channel.send(msg) # Blocks if channel is in cooldown due to slow mode, any way to check before sending?
```

Comment: @matszwecja it keeps stuck until the cooldown finish

Comment: [`TextChannel.slowmode_delay`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel#discord.TextChannel.slowmode_delay)

Comment: It tries to handle the ratelimiting intelligently by waiting (which is the exact opposite of what you want). If you use the raw http response it will give you an amount of time to wait, or you can keep a timestamp of your last message or give your bot the necessary permissions to bypass it.